# How to access bound key of Vue.js list item?

Tags: vue.js

In Vue if you write something like

```
<div v-for="item in items" />
```

there's a warning that you should supply a `key` for list items. So then if you write

```
<MyComponent v-for"item in items" :key="item.someProp" />
```

the warning goes away, but how do you access that key in the actual component?
 I've tried inspecting it and I don't see anything like `key` in the props.

This is where I'm trying to access the key:

```
<!-- MyComponent.vue -->
<script>
export default {
  created() {
    // this is where i'd like to access the key
    const key = ?;
    const someOtherData = this.$config[key];
  }
}
</script>
```

Basically I'd like to reuse the same key to do a lookup in my app config.

Comment: Why do you want to access it?

Comment: I use it to look up other props in my app config.

Comment: but why you need key for it, [key](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) is used for efficient rendering of list in vue. You can just do `item.prop1`, `item.prop2` and so on.

Comment: Because my config file is structured using the same keys and I need to look up some other data

Comment: Just change the name of `key`. You can use some thing like `propKey`

Comment: That's how I worked around it -- just feels weird having a dummy prop just for that.

Comment: Had the same issue, will use additional prop for this

Answer (score 0):

you can use it inside your component the same way you assigned it because its a prop of your item, just type

```
 const key = item.someProp;
```